# cmd says invalid syntax. I can't find anything wrong with this sample code

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to run a program that collects the url's from a log file and prints them onto a new file using command line arguments. The output says invalid syntax at the def main() line. I can't find anything wrong with this and I'm using python 3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYAUT.jpg

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

# Google's Python Class
# http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/

import os
import re
import sys
import urllib.request

"""Logpuzzle exercise
Given an apache logfile, find the puzzle urls and download the images.

Here's what a puzzle url looks like:
10.254.254.28 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:13:48 -0700] "GET /~foo/puzzle-bar-aaab.jpg HTTP/1.0" 302 528 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
"""


def read_urls(filename):
  """Returns a list of the puzzle urls from the given log file,
  extracting the hostname from the filename itself.
  Screens out duplicate urls and returns the urls sorted into
  increasing order."""
  # +++your code here+++
  f = open(filename, 'rU')
  text = f.read()
  urls = re.findall('[\S]*puzzle[\S]*', text)
  urlList = []
  fullUrlList = []
  for url in urls:
    if not url in urlList:
      urlList.append(filename+url)
  fullUrlList = sorted(urlList)
  return fullUrlList




def download_images(img_urls, dest_dir):
  """Given the urls already in the correct order, downloads
  each image into the given directory.
  Gives the images local filenames img0, img1, and so on.
  Creates an index.html in the directory
  with an img tag to show each local image file.
  Creates the directory if necessary.
  """
  # +++your code here+++
  if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    os.makedirs(dest_dir)
  i = 0
  for url in img_urls:
    localname = 'img%d' %i
    urllib.request.retrieve(url, os.path.join(dest_dir, localname)




def main():
  args = sys.argv[1:]

  if not args:
    print ('usage: [--todir dir] logfile ')
    sys.exit(1)

  todir = None
  if args[0] == '--todir':
    todir = args[1]
    del args[0:2]


  img_urls = read_urls(args[0])

  if todir:
    download_images(img_urls, todir)
  else:
    print ('\n'.join(img_urls))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please include the traceback

Comment: have you mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: I have used proper indentation.

Comment: The image you added says the error is line 61, which is the first line of the posted code. You need to include the code that goes before the syntax error, not all the stuff after it that didn't even get parsed.

Comment: I agree with @TigerhawkT3 , you need to post the whole file. I suspect something is wrong right above the function definition and the parser didn't expect a function definition. Just my guess ;)

Comment: I'd say it doesn't need the whole file; just the statement immediately preceding the `def main():`.

Comment: And there we go: the statement directly above it is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 :-| ..I really wish this doesn't happen again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `urllib.request.retrieve(url, os.path.join(dest_dir, localname)` you need to add a closing parentheses. :) <3

Answer (score 0):

Close the parentheses.

```
urllib.request.retrieve(url, os.path.join(dest_dir, localname)
                                                              ^
```

The syntax error is almost always in the statement right above the one the interpreter points out to you.